# "Moment cannot be found by angular-moment" when trying to test with karma & jasmine - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, momentjs, karma-jasmine, angular-moment

**My app runs correctly and the AngularMoment works perfectly with MomentJS.**

Lately I tried to implement **unit-testing** into my app on `grunt watch`, using Karma and Jasmine. All the modules seem to load fine, but only the `moment` can not be found by `angular-moment`. *(error message below):*

```
Error during loading: Uncaught Error: Moment cannot be found by 
angular-moment! Please reference to: https://github.com/urish/angular- 
moment in js/libs/angular-moment.js line 27
```

All the dependencies are loaded into the `karma.config.js` and still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the files in `karma.config.js` matters. We have to load certain libraries before the others, as stated below.

```
files: [
    //Dependencies of the app
    'dist/js/libs/jquery.js',
    'dist/js/libs/angular.js',
    'dist/js/libs/angular-mocks.js',
    'dist/js/libs/moment.js',
    'dist/js/libs/*.js',
    .
    .
    .
]
```